# Android change tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am following this tutorial for android tabs:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

I copied code and it works now.But I am listing items in games tab when user clicks any item I want to show this item details to user.I have to change layout for this.I tried this algorithm:

```
1)User clicks item
2)Run onclick function
3)Change layout with this code "setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)" in onclick function
4)When user clicks the back button run this code : "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)"
```

But when user clicks the back button layout is not changing.What is your suggestions ?

Ps:I don't want to use activity because I'll build a chat system,activites is not running at background.

Comment: It is not recommended to change your layout without starting another Activity. That is not the way it works.

Comment: hmm.Can I add a tab for details but I don't to show this tab on top.Can I do this ? @joao2fast4u

Comment: You could start a new Activity for showing details. And the tabs would only be shown when the user pressed back.